# Unable to Mock ILogger in Nunit

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nunit, ilogger

Net core and NUnit test case. I have my controller as below.

```
public class MyController : ControllerBase
    {
      public MyController(ILogger<MyController > logger)
        {
            this.Logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
        }
    private readonly ILogger<MyController > Logger;

    public async Task<ActionResult> GetList()
    {
      this.Logger.LogInformation($"MyList: Some results came");
    }
 }
```

Then below my unit test case.

```
 public class MyControllerTests
 {
   private Mock<ILogger<MyController>> Logger = new Mock<ILogger<MyController>>();
   internal MyController myController;
   public MyControllerTests()
        {
            this.myController= new MyController(this.Logger.Object);
        }
    [Test]
        public async Task ListTest()
        {
           Logger.Verify(
               x => x.Log(
                   LogLevel.Information,
                   It.IsAny<EventId>(),
                   It.Is<It.IsAnyType>((o, t) => string.Equals("MyList: Some results came", o.ToString(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)),
                   It.IsAny<Exception>(),
                   (Func<It.IsAnyType, Exception, string>)It.IsAny<object>()),
         //rest of the code but i am getting error in above line
        }
 }
```

Above code gives error

> Moq.MockException :
> ILogger.Log(LogLevel.Information, 0, ListTest
> : Successfully Fetched the Results, null, Func<FormattedLogValues,
> Exception, string>) invocation failed with mock behavior Strict.
> All invocations on the mock must have a corresponding setup.

Can someone help me to fix this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Try `new Mock<ILogger<MyController>>(MockBehavior.Loose);`

Comment: Which logic are you going to test? There is nothing except logger verification

Comment: As the error message says you need to setup method call on mock object before you can verify them. Also the test code does not have anything which is calling any method in Logger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close. Here's an [article](https://christianfindlay.com/2020/07/03/ilogger/) about this. Here are the two working verification's I've come up with:

```
        _logTest.Process();
        _loggerMock.Verify(l => l.Log(
            LogLevel.Information,
            It.IsAny<EventId>(),
            It.IsAny<It.IsAnyType>(),
            It.IsAny<Exception>(),
            (Func<It.IsAnyType, Exception, string>)It.IsAny<object>()), Times.Exactly(1));
```

This version allows you to get more specific:

```
        _loggerMock.Verify
        (
            l => l.Log
            (
                //Check the severity level
                LogLevel.Error,
                //This may or may not be relevant to your scenario
                It.IsAny<EventId>(),
                //This is the magical Moq code that exposes internal log processing from the extension methods
                It.Is<It.IsAnyType>((state, t) =>
                    //This confirms that the correct log message was sent to the logger. {OriginalFormat} should match the value passed to the logger
                    //Note: messages should be retrieved from a service that will probably store the strings in a resource file
                    CheckValue(state, "MyList: Some results came", "{OriginalFormat}") &&
                    //This confirms that an argument with a key of "recordId" was sent with the correct value
                    //In Application Insights, this will turn up in Custom Dimensions
                    CheckValue(state, recordId, nameof(recordId))
            ),
            //Confirm the exception type
            It.IsAny<ArgumentNullException>(),
            //Accept any valid Func here. The Func is specified by the extension methods
            (Func<It.IsAnyType, Exception, string>)It.IsAny<object>()),
            //Make sure the message was logged the correct number of times
            Times.Exactly(1)
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

In general you should rely on DI in tests as well as in runtime. The following library contains a test logger which you may use in tests: https://www.nuget.org/packages/com.github.akovac35.Logging.Testing/

Usage samples are available here: https://github.com/akovac35/Logging.Samples

Disclaimer: I am the author of the above.

**Basically you would proceed as follows:**

Use NullLogger by default:

```cs
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{        
    private ILogger _logger = NullLogger.Instance;
    
    protected MyController(ILogger<MyController> logger = null)
    {
        if (logger != null) _logger = logger;
    }
}
```

Now wire up tests:

```cs
using com.github.akovac35.Logging.Testing;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using NUnit.Framework;
using Shared.Mocks;
using System;

namespace TestApp
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class TestLoggingExamples
    {
        [OneTimeSetUp]
        public void OneTimeSetUp()
        {
            customOnWrite = writeContext => {
                Console.WriteLine(writeContext);
            };

            customOnBeginScope = scopeContext => {
                Console.WriteLine(scopeContext);
            };

            serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
            serviceCollection.AddTransient(typeof(MyController));

            // Register TestLogger using extension method
            serviceCollection.AddTestLogger(onWrite: customOnWrite, onBeginScope: customOnBeginScope);
        }

        private IServiceCollection serviceCollection;

        private Action<WriteContext> customOnWrite;
        private Action<ScopeContext> customOnBeginScope;

        [Test]
        public void Test_WithLoggingToTestConsole_Works()
        {
            // The service provider should be defined on per-test level or logger writes will accumulate and may result in OOM - clean them with testSink.Clear()
            var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
            var controller = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyController>();
            controller.Invoke();

            var testSink = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ITestSink>();

            Assert.IsTrue(testSink.Writes.Count > 0);
            Assert.IsTrue(testSink.Scopes.Count > 0);
        }
    }
}
```

testSink.Writes contains WriteContext objects where specific log messages may be asserted:

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;

namespace com.github.akovac35.Logging.Testing
{
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerDisplay("{ToString()}")]
    public class WriteContext
    {
        public LogLevel LogLevel { get; set; }

        public EventId EventId { get; set; }

        public object State { get; set; }

        public Exception Exception { get; set; }

        public Func<object, Exception, string> Formatter { get; set; }

        public ScopeContext Scope { get; set; }

        public ILogger Logger { get; set; }

        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }

        public int ThreadId { get; set; }

        public virtual string Message
        {
            get
            {
                return Formatter(State, Exception);
            }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"[{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}] {ThreadId} {LogLevel} EventId: {EventId}{(Scope != null ? $" Scope: <{Scope}>" : "")} Message: {Message}{(Exception != null ? $"{Environment.NewLine}{Exception}" : "")}";
        }
    }
}
```